# Converting Input List that is read in String to List in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am reading a file that has list. Below is the input file.

```
[1,2,3,4]
[42]
[1,1,2,3,5,8]
[]
```

Now as you can see there are lists which is read as string character and I am trying to convert it into an actual list.
Below is the code I'm using.

```
_list = list(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
_final_list = []
    for n in _list:
        try:
            n = int(n)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        if isinstance(n, int):
            _final_list.append(n)
```

Now my code works fine until a number is more than one digit. For example 42 would become 4, 2. Which is not what I want.

My code generates below result.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 2] <--- FALSE
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
[]
```

What should I do here to accomplish this task without using libraries such as `ast`

Comment: Why don't you want to use `ast`? Why are you doing this in the first place? Why not use a built in serialization method like `json` or `pickle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strip the endings and split by commas.

```
def str_to_list(s):
    return [int(i) for i in s.strip('][').split(',') if i]
```

Comment: Awesome! This is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

you can use ast.literal_eval:

```
import ast

_final_list = []
for line in _list:
    python_object = ast.literal_eval(line)        
    if isinstance(python_object, list):
        _final_list.extend(python_object)
```

or you can use regular expression:

```
import re

_final_list = []
for line in _list:
    my_list = [e.group() for e in re.finditer(r'\d+', line)]
    _final_list.extend(my_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! But As I mentioned before, I don't want to use ast.

Comment: any reason to not use?

Comment: I am sure there is a way to do it without using libraries. I am preparing for a competition and I will not be able to memorize all libraries there are in the competition. I am trying to solve this problem just in python.

Comment: For practice wise, I do not want to use it. But to solve the problem, I would've used ast right away

Comment: @Khan check  now my answer

Comment: Awesome! Thank you :)